# Heroku application error - Gemfile.lock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gemfile.lock

I keep running into the application error on Heroku website after I write `git push heroku master`. Does this have something to do with this?:

WARNINGS:
Removing 'Gemfile.lock' because it was generated on windows.
 Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
 This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
 In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.

and if so how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Edit: http://gyazo.com/bc40680795ac3d7c7134fcf84d97c4a1

Comment: It's a standard thing - we get it. If you give us a trace of `heroku logs`, we'll be able to help you better

Comment: That warning doesn't sound like anything that could generate an application error. What is the actual application error?